# How to use cocoapods or similar functions in the SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I want to use cocoapods or similar functions in my own SDK. what should I do.

I tried to refer to the third-party library by direct reference, but there was a path problem when calling it.
swift please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include third party pods in your custom SDK you can directly include them in your podfile and use them.
when you will be publishing your SDK then in the podspec file you will have to mention all the pods that you are using

```
spec.dependency "SDWebImage", "~> 5.11.1"
spec.dependency "SwiftLint"
spec.dependency "IQKeyboardManagerSwift"
```

Like this in your podspec file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate more or share a link, the part about "directly include them in your podfile and use them"?How do I do it？

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to use it please.

Comment: yes what i mean is that in normal project we use podfile to use third party similarly we can use in creating our custom framework. after install the pods we have to use .xcworkspace and wherever we want to use pods we can import them in our class and use them directly. also u have to install all these pods in your project that will be integrating your sdk